# How do you generate a random matrix in R with a constant colSum value?

Tags: r, matrix, random

I'm looking for a way to generate a series of matrices where all the column sums are equal to a specific value.
I thought I could generate random matrices and check each one to filter out where colSums= value needed, but that doesn't seem to work.
Also, how do we generate random matrices in R with both positive and negative values?

Comment: for the second question, you can have a look to `?runif`, eg try `runif(your_desired_number, -1, 1)`

Comment: Please give an example of such a matrix : your question is too broad as it is.

Comment: @priya12 hello if the answer to the question solves your problem, can you click 'accept' it so that other people can benefit from it? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this. This is a function that creates a matrix filled with random numbers from a normal distribution. Then it centers all columns to 0 and adds up the desired number.

```
RandomMatrixColsum = function(mycolsum=1, dim=c(10, 10), ...){
  m  <- matrix(rnorm(prod(dim), ...), ncol=dim[2])
  ms <- scale(m, center=T, scale=F) + mycolsum/dim[1]
  return(ms)
}
RandomMatrixColsum(8)
```

If you want to make sure to have both positive and negative values in your matrix, you can increase the standard deviation of the `rnorm` by adding an argument `sd=...` to the function call, or also force the sd to be equal to the mean.