# Is there a way to make a random number matrix in R where all rows = a given value?

Tags: r, random

I am trying to make a dummy dataset to test a model I have built on real data. I want to make a matrix of 11 columns, each row of which sums to 100 as its percentage data.

I can make a sample matrix of the right dimensions, for example, 100 rows by 11 columns

```r
set.seed(42)

ranMat <- matrix(sample(seq(0:100), 1100, replace = TRUE), ncol = 11)
```

but I don't know where to start to ask it to make each row sum to 100.

The related examples I have found on stackoverflow are in languages I don't know (i.e. Python and Matlab), and so can't port over so to speak.
Close, but not the same are for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454918/how-do-you-generate-a-random-matrix-in-r-with-a-constant-colsum-value) but I don't want to take them from a normal distribution and I don't want negative numbers.

Comment: Just generate a random matrix and then normalize to the row sum.

Comment: If you need the results to be integers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161406/how-do-i-generate-a-uniform-random-integer-partition

Comment: Do they need to be integers? Or is non-negative the the only criteria? And what do you mean by "don't want to take them from a normal distribution"? I don't think that would work generally, but it seems weird to single out - are you interested in other distributions (Poisson or Exponential or Gamma or Uniform or ...)?

Comment: They don't need to be integers, and I don't want them to be other distributions either. In the answer I referenced they filled the matrix from a normal distribution, which I did not want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just divide the random matrix by its `rowSums` and multiply by `100`.

```r
set.seed(42) 
ranMat <- matrix(sample(seq(0:100), 1100, replace = TRUE), ncol = 11)

norm_ranMat <- ranMat / rowSums(ranMat) * 100

head(rowSums(norm_ranMat))
#> [1] 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I really like how elegantly simple this solution is. I was wading through looking for  built in solutions in functions, when simple maths would do it! Thanks Dan